# How could I see the output of my Python code in the echo area?

Tags: python, shell, echo-area

When I press `C-c C-c`(`python-shell-send-buffer`), I get output shown below. Afterwards when I do the same operation (`C-c C-c`) I always see `Sent: #!/usr/bin/env python3...` in the echo area.

- I just want to see the output rather than seeing the send code.

=> How can I instead see only the output of the code in the echo area (if possible)? or show it on the minibuffer compact as possible and close it when `C-g` is pressed.

### [image]

The output in the `*Python*` buffer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
... 
... print("hello world")
import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/mx/m3c2fd193h169gg6nd5x3p480000gn/T/pyK57xMh''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/mx/m3c2fd193h169gg6nd5x3p480000gn/T/pyK57xMh''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/alper/code/doo.py''', 'exec'));
hello world
#!/usr/bin/env python3
... 
... print("hello world")
import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/mx/m3c2fd193h169gg6nd5x3p480000gn/T/pyK57xMh''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/mx/m3c2fd193h169gg6nd5x3p480000gn/T/pyK57xMh''');exec(compile(__code, '''/Users/alper/code/doo.py''', 'exec'));
hello world
```

---

My setup in my init file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))

(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"
      python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning nil
      flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "python3"
      python-shell-completion-native-enable nil
      python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters '("python3")
      elpy-shell-echo-output nil ; https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1550#issuecomment-574512892
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and [this](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1307#issuecomment-382740696) is a solution I found that works for me:

```
pip3 install gnureadline
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/
mv readline.cpython-37m-darwin.so readline.cpython-37m-darwin.so.bak
```

Some information that might help:
OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7.
Emacs: 27.2.
python: 3.7.4.

And here is an unofficial explanation that I understood: the `gnureadline` is the readline package that should be used by default here, it naturally comes with some version of python but maybe not the one that comes naturally with MacOS, according to the [gnureadline's website](https://pypi.org/project/gnureadline/). Instead the MacOS uses another packages for readline module. And if emacs need to use that readline, it requires some code(the unwanted 'import codecs blablabla') to do so. So here the solution used the `gnureadline` and unables the default readline module because the one(default readline) in lib-dynload comes before the one in side-packages(gnureadline). So we need to get the default one out of the way.

Comment: I tried this, but when I import `gnureadline` I get weird printouts every time I send a statement to shell - `__PYTHON_EL_eval(...)`